# Network adapter identification from WLAN disconnect event

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, event-viewer

Want to attach specific task to wifi adapter disconnect event, but need (just disconnected) adapter identification (name, guid, etc..). Unfortunatelly its not present in generated 4004 event. There could be multiple wlan adapter present, so blindly read name of wlan adapter from system is not suitable solution. Is there any way to map this (or other) event do related network adapter or profile?

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile" Guid="{fbcfac3f-8459-419f-8e48-1f0b49cdb85e}" /> 
  <EventID>4004</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-12T09:17:28.1702393Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>9047</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1968" ThreadID="2216" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>MACHINE</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="NewInternetConnectionProfile">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectionCostChanged">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="DomainConnectivityLevelChanged">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="NetworkConnectivityLevelChanged">true</Data> 
  <Data Name="HostNameChanged">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="WwanRegistrationStateChanged">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="TetheringOperationalStateChanged">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="TetheringClientCountChanged">false</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```